# Azure Pipeline - launch server inside test application

Tags: azure, azure-devops, localhost, xunit, dotnetcorecli

I have a XUnit project, that when starting up initializes a server in the class constructor:

```
public OPCUASampleServerTest(OPCTagList oPCTagList)
{
    MySampleServer server = new(true, 3600, null);
    this.thread = new Thread(() => server.Run());
    this.thread.Start();
    this._taglist = oPCTagList.Taglist;
}
```

The tests utilizing the server, communicates to it via `localhost` and all works fine on my machine. I have also tested it by cloning the code to assure that everything is present in the repository. Everything compiles as expected. I am trying to have the same result on an Azure pipeline. I have a working pipeline that builds and runs the initial test cases, WITHOUT the server. Now after adding this `OPCUASampleServerTest` the test fails on the server, but not on my machine. The error is that it is not able to connect to the server

```
OPCUAClass opc = new("localhost", "51210", this._taglist, 300, false);
bool connected = opc.InitializeOPCUAClient(); //returns false on server, and true on running it on my own machine
```

I am therefore thinking that the issue is that it cannot see/connect to `localhost`. Is there some specific setting I am missing in my test function in the pipeline that looks like this:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Test xUnit
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/OPCDLL.Test.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --collect "Code coverage" --no-build'
    testRunTitle: 'Generic Repository Tests'
    publishTestResults: true
```

Running what I interpret as the same function using the dotnet CLI:

```
dotnet test OPCDLL.Test.csproj  --configuration Release --collect "Code coverage" --no-build --framework net5.0
```

I get 4 passed tests, as it should be. So there is definitely something spurious in the azure run?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64502381/azure-devops-pipeline-tests-that-pass-locally-fail-on-the-pipeline.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT so your saying it is a timing issue? Any method for me to debug this? I am not specifically relying on timings, but I guess it is happening in the tcp.opc communication protocol implemented by OPC foundation. Still shouldn't a test that is running fine in VS and via commandline  be able to run on the Azure Pipeline?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT if you refer to the tool they reference `Visual Studio Test Platform Installer` I cannot find this in the available tasks on the pipeline

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT `- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **/OPCDLL.Test.csproj
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    runInParallel: false
    runTestsInIsolation: true
    diagnosticsEnabled: true
    rerunFailedTests: true
    rerunMaxAttempts: 3`
I tried with VSTest, but it does not find the tests, I guess that .NET5.0 is not supported?

Comment: Are you raising 1 server per test?

Comment: No only this one extra test

Comment: Can you add some info about the library you use to raise this server? Have you tried using OWIN? are you using hosted agents or self-hosted with a VM? Maybe you are missing some installation in your build machine if you are using self-hosted agents.